# How to eliminate #NAME? error Excel for a long list of IDs starting with =

Tags: excel

I have a long list of ids in excel. (a couple 100k rows) and every so often one of the ids will start with an equals. This causes excel to think it's a formula and gives me the #NAME? error. I know about adding a quote to the beginning of a forumla to make it text, but is there a faster way to do this since I have so many rows?

I also tried converting the cells to text and concatenating a ' at the beginning, but it still comes out as a #name? error.

Thank you!

Comment: Try also to format the cell as text, Format cells/Number tab/Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IFNA(FORMULATEXT(A1),A1)` will do it, assuming `A1` contains the datum.

`FORMULATEXT(A1)` will "undo" the conversion of `=Something` back to the original text, but returns `#N/A` if the cell doesn't contain a formula. The latter is circumvented with `IFNA`.

(Obviously you can copy and paste-special values once you've added what presumably is an extra column in your workbook to deal with this calculation.)

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

running this small macro:

```
Sub FixEquals()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, s As String
    Set rng = Range("D:D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each r In rng
        s = r.Formula
        r.Clear
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        r.Value = s
    Next r
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]